# Deriving formula for derivative

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I have a formula in my book for differentiating numerically.

$$f'(x_0)=\frac{1}{12h}[-25f(x_0)+48f(x_0+h)-36f(x_0+2h)+16f(x_0+3h)-3f(x_0+4h)]+\frac{4}{5}f^{(5)}(\xi)$$

I was wondering if anyone could explain how we know the formula is true?  (By the way the term with $\xi$ is the estimate for the error which appears in the Taylor Series and $h$ is step size) I think I have to take the Taylor Series of $f(x_0 +h)$ and $f(x_0-h)$ and $f(x_0+2h)$ and $f(x_0-2h)$ etc... and then some sort of linear combination of those Taylor Series makes the formula, but how do we know which linear combination of the Taylor Series we are supposed to do?

Or perhaps there is an easier way to derive the formula?

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: What is assumed or known about $f$ and $\xi$? Is $f\in C^5$? Is the statement that for every $x_0$ there exists $\xi\in(x_0-7h,x_0+7h)$ so that the equation holds? Some more details would make the formula more meaningful.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta $\xi$ is between $x_0$ and $x_0+4h$. If $C^5$ means that I can take the derivative $5$ times, then yes, $f\in C^5$.

Comment: $f\in C^5$ means that $f$ is five times continuously differentiable. That is, you can take the derivative five times and the fifth derivative is continuous. But thanks, now the question makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

The Taylor Series is a polynomial in $h$, let

$$a+bh+ch^2+dh^3+eh^4+fh^5\cdots$$

Evaluating it for the first multiples of the step gives

$0:a\\
h:a+bh+ch^2+dh^3+eh^4+fh^5+\cdots\\
2h:a+2bh+4ch^2+8dh^3+16eh^4+32fh^5+\cdots\\
3h:a+3bh+9ch^2+27dh^3+81eh^4+243fh^5+\cdots\\
4h:a+4bh+16ch^2+64dh^3+256eh^4+1024fh^5+\cdots\\
5h:a+5bh+25cv+125dh^3+625eh^4+3125fh^5+\cdots\\
\cdots$

The trick is to form a linear combination such that the of all powers coefficients are $0$, except that of $h$. To get a fifth order formula, we need to solve the following linear system:

$a:\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta+\epsilon=0\\
bh:\beta+2\gamma+3\delta+4\epsilon=1\\
ch^2:\beta+4\gamma+9\delta+16\epsilon=0\\
dh^3:\beta+8\gamma+27\delta+64\epsilon=0\\
eh^4:\beta+16\gamma+81\delta+256\epsilon=0.$

The solution is precisely
$$\alpha=-\frac{25}{12},\beta=\frac{48}{12},\gamma=-\frac{36}{12},\delta=\frac{16}{12},\epsilon=-\frac{3}{12}.$$

Comment: cool, I didn't realize we could get a system of linear equations with the Taylor polynomials. Thanks for your help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try finding:
$$4f(x+h)-3f(x+2h)+\frac43f(x+3h)-\frac14f(x+4h)$$
Which comes out to be:
$$\small 4f(x+h)-3f(x+2h)+\frac43f(x+3h)-\frac14f(x+4h)=\frac{25}{12}f(x)+hf'(x)-\frac15h^5f^{(5)}(x)+O(h^6)$$
So $f'(x)$ is:
$$f'(x)=\frac1h[-\frac{25}{12}f(x)+4f(x+h)-3f(x+2h)+\frac43f(x+3h)-\frac14f(x+4h)+\frac15h^5f^{(5)}(x)+O(h^6)]$$

---

How did I found the coefficients?:
By taylor' theorem:
$$f(x+kh)=f(x)+kf'(x)h+\frac12k^2h^2f''(x)+...+\frac1{n!}k^nh^nf^{(n)}(x)+R_{n+1}$$
So you needed to solve:
$$ 
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
a+2b+3c+4d=1\\
a+4b+9c+16d=0\\
a+8b+27c+64d=0\\
a+16b+81c+256d=0
\end{array}\right\}
$$
which is easily solvable as last three equations are easy to manipulate and give:
$$a=4,b=-3,c=4/3,d=-1/4$$